# Close a one windowHandler at the Webview

Tags: selenium, c#, appium

I am writing scripts to automate a hybrid application.
On my app I have two windowHandles.

For example, after performing some actions when I execute below code I get "2" windows as the windowHandles value.

```
ReadOnlyCollection<string> windowHandles = InitialiseAppium.driver.WindowHandles;
```

So at the script I need to close the windowHandles[1] window and navigate back to 0th window.

I tried doing this with:

```
driver.close();
driver.Navigate().Back();
```

But no luck yet:

```
_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+__+
```

This is what i currently have:

```
ReadOnlyCollection<string> windowHandles = InitialiseAppium.driver.WindowHandles;

InitialiseAppium.driver.SwitchTo().Window(windowHandles[0]);
InitialiseAppium.driver.Close();
```

Not working.

Comment: You should get your two handles in a list or array, try iterating your list or array.

Comment: tried by ..No luck

Comment: can you please show us what you tried?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you follow the below approach:

- Before performing the action you mentioned, store the default(main) window handle in a string variable, say CurrentHandle using `driver.getWindowHandles()`
- After the action, use the code you mentioned to get all windows in ReadOnlyCollection windowHandles
- Iterate windowHandles and check if CurrentHandle is not equal to windowHandles loop instance
- If loop instance is not equal to CurrentHandle, then `driver.switchTo().window(windowHandles[i])` and then do `driver.close()`
- After the loop, use `driver.switchTo().window(CurrentHandle)`

Comment: WIthout checking any conditions i tried closing both 0th and 1st web views, But nothing get closed.

Comment: Have you ensured you used the statement driver.switchTo().window("window-handle") before you call driver.close() ?

Comment: Yes , i did. i mention it at the 2nd time when i edit the post

Answer (score 0):

To close a new window, you first new to set the context on this new window:

```
element.Click();  // opens a new window

// store the handle of the main window
String winMain = driver.WindowHandle;

// set the context on the second window and close it
foreach (String winX in driver.WindowHandles) {
  if (!winX.Equals(winMain)) {
    driver.SwitchTo().Window(winX);
    driver.Close();
  }
}

// set the context back to the main window
driver.SwitchTo().Window(winMain);
```

Note that `WindowHandles` returns a collection of handles where the first handle is not guarantied to be the first window. So you should not try to get an handle by index.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this to close a single window,

```
driver.switchTo().window(windowHandles[1]).close();
```

In case of loop, you can try something like this,

```
for x in range(1, 6):
    driver.switchTo().window(window_handles[x]).close();
```